# When is the memory allocated for UICollectionViewCell rasterizations freed?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

So, in my app I have a bunch of view controllers that use `UICollectionView` as their main structure. These contain cells composed of an image and some overlay text and there are a potentially large number of these cells that will be created throughout the course of navigating the app (well into the hundreds and possibly 1000+. It's a huge catalog of content). I've found the enabling rasterization:

```
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

**drastically** speeds up performance, making the framerate go from ~31fps to ~58fps, but, as expected, the memory for the app steadily increases.

So my question is when are these cached rasterized images removed? Is it only when the app is stopped? Or is it when the views containing them are deinit? Is there a way to manually force them to be removed if it's the former?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]The cached layers are removed if unused for 100ms.

Here are important notes from WWDC 2014

- The image is composited on the GPU
- Cache size is limited to 2.5x of screen size

http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/419xxli6f60a6bs/419/419_advanced_graphics_and_animation_performance.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Do you know what they mean by "cache size is limited to 2.5x of the screen size"? Does that mean the combined area of all the cached images can only be 2.5x the area of the screen? And I'm assuming there if the cache limit is exceeded it'll just evict older images, right?